# When summing values from 2 arrays how can I cap the value in the new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

The idea is to blend the rbg values of two colors together AND keep my code clean. An rgb can't have a value over 255. What I'm trying to do is after the values are added if the number is over 255, keep it at 255.

One way I've tried works, but I feel like there is repetitive code. Another way I've tried seems to be on the right track, but does NOT work.

This is the way that works

```
const mixColors = (color1, color2) => {
    let red = color1[0] + color2[0];
    let green = color1[1] + color2[1];
    let blue = color1[2] + color2[2];

    if (red > 255) {
        red = 255;
    }
    if (green > 255) {
        green = 255;
    }
    if (blue > 255) {
        blue = 255;
    } else console.log(`rgb: ${red}, ${green}, ${blue}`);
};
mixColors([235, 45, 0], [100, 27, 47]);
```

This is me trying to simplify the code, but it not working. As a separate question, why doesn't this way work? The values get added properly and it seems to just skip of my if statement.

```
const mixColors = (color1, color2) => {
    const newColor = color1.map((a, i) => a + color2[i]);

    if (newColor > 255) {
        newColor[i] = 255;
    }

    console.log(newColor);
    return newColor;
};
mixColors([235, 45, 0], [100, 27, 47]);
```

Is the first way the best way and I'm over thinking this? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `newColor` is an array, so `newColor > 255` doesn't make sense (and doesn't work). Put a `Math.min` inside the `.map` callback instead:

```js
const mixColors = (color1, color2) => color1.map((num, i) => Math.min(num + color2[i], 255));
console.log(mixColors([235, 45, 0], [100, 27, 47]));
```

Comment: oh, cool. I haven't gotten to math.min yet.

`const mixColors = (color1, color2) => {
 const newColor = [];
 color1.map((val, idx) => {
  if (val + color2[idx] > 255) {
   newColor.push(255);
  } else {
   newColor.push(val + color2[idx]);
  }
 });
 console.log('arr', newColor);
};

mixColors([235, 45, 0], [100, 27, 47]);`

this was what I had come up with, with the help of someone else. Your way is even shorter. Thank you for the help

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)